# AWS - 401 Access Denied - Details correct, permissions set

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

### The problem

About a year ago I setup calls to different AWS, I am now trying to get it working again by simply setting up a new key. The issue is that I keep getting 'Access to X denied.' and I'm not too sure what else I can do in terms of troubleshooting.

At the moment I am trying to access the GetReports API, and I get the following error:

```
Caught Exception: Access to Reports.RequestReport is denied 
Response Status Code: 401 
Error Code: AccessDenied
```

---

### The setup

1. I am selling on Amazon using email address A.
2. I have setup email address B as a 'Current User' in the User Permissions area of Seller Central for email address A.
3. I have logged into the developer console for email address B and I have created an access key and secret.
4. I am using this access key and secret in the config for the API but it is not working, I get a 401 error.

---

### What I have tried

I have deleted the existing keys on email address B and created new ones.

---

I have tried a different API call.

---

I have checked all of the other config information (e.g. Merchant ID and Marketplace Token).

---

Following the steps from [Amazon's documentation](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_Registering.html) I attempted to authorize my developer account, which was met with the following error:

> This Developer Account Number XXXXXXXXXXXX is not valid for the GB
>   marketplace. Please make sure you are registering on the correct
>   Amazon MWS site. If you are registering on the correct Amazon MWS
>   site, please contact the developer you are attempting to authorise in
>   order to obtain a valid Developer Account Number from Amazon MWS for
>   any marketplace in the EU region. For more information, see
>   “Registering to use Amazon MWS” in the Amazon MWS Developer Guide.

As far as I can see, the developer account is setup for the GB marketplace, and the last time I used this account it all worked fine and I have no reason to believe anything has changed.

---

**What else can I try, what else could be wrong?**

---

Comment: which resource you are trying to access and how have you sourced the credentials ?

Comment: I am trying to use the `RequestReport` call, the access and secret key were setup in the developer account of email address B.

Comment: Have you gone through this https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_Registering.html ?

Comment: Yes, I have just edited my question to detail what happens when I follow those instructions

Comment: @MarkOverton - I would assume since you linked en_US documentation, you have accidentally signed up for the US dev account, I'd check where it say's your location is in terms of your service

Comment: @CanO'Spam I used the link provided by error404, but the [UK version](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/dev_guide/DG_Registering.html) reads the exact same, the account has previously worked so I am pretty confident it is setup for the UK marketplace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You need to register an app

When logged in to Seller Central, you need to go to `Apps & Services` dropdown and select `Develop Apps`, from here you'll need to add a new app and fill out the form.

It can take up to 30 days for Amazon to process your request, but this will give you access to the MWS calls, once it has gone through you'll need to use the `Access Key` and `Client Secret` details listed in Developer Central under "My Developer Information" when making your MWS requests.

You'll also find your Developer ID here that you will be able to authorise using the process you mentioned in your question, once the app is authorised you shouldn't get the error you were previously getting.